# What do group theorists mean when they say that $g \mapsto gH$ is undefined when $H$ is non-normal?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

If $H$ is a normal subgroup then the function $G \to G/H$ that takes $g$ to $gH$ is well-defined.

If $H$ is an non-normal subgroup then the function $G \to G/H$ that takes $g$ to $gH$ is not well-defined.

Typically when a function $f$ is not well-defined that means that $x = y$ does not imply that $f(x) = f(y)$. So when group theorists say that the morphism $g \mapsto gH$ is not defined for non-normal subgroups, that typically would mean that $g_1 = g_2$ does not imply $g_1H = g_2H$. But it seems obvious from inspection that $g_1 = g_2$ always implies $g_1H = g_2H$, whether $H$ is normal or not.

So what do group theorists mean when they say that the function $g \mapsto gH$ is not well-defined when $H$ is non-normal?

Comment: your title says *action* of $G$ on $G/H,$ but I don't see any discussion of that in the body

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I was sloppy with my title. I edited it.

Comment: Do you understand $g_1Hg_2H$ is not well-defined when $H$ is not normal (or is that your question)?

Comment: Yes, that is my question @J.W.Tanner

Comment: The map group theorists want should be a **homomorphism**, so they would like to have $f(g_1g_2)=f(g_1)f(g_2)$, i.e. $g_1g_2H=(g_1H)(g_2H)$. But for subgroups that are NOT normal the latter condition is not met, hence the function (even though well-defined) will not yield a homomorphism.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the function is well-defined, but it can't be made into a group homomorphism.

Comment: The statement "$G\to G/H$ is not well defined" is extremely misleading (who even says that?). Becase (1) $G\to G/H$ is always well defined and (2) it doesn't make sense to talk about homomorphisms when $G/H$ is not a group. Those "group theorists" simply mean that $G/H$ is not a group and so $G\to G/H$ is only a function. But I would slap anyone phrasing this as "$G\to G/H$ is not well defined".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that it isn't a homomorphism. Take a $g$ s.t. $gHg^{-1} \neq H$ (such $g$ exists, otherwise $H$ is normal). Call $\pi : G \rightarrow G/H$.

If $\pi$ is a homomorphism, then $H = \pi(1) = \pi(gg^{-1}) = \pi(g)\pi(g^{-1})= gHg^{-1} H$.

But $H \neq gHg^{-1}H$! Obviously $H \subseteq gHg^{-1}H$ (if $h \in H$ then $h = g1g^{-1}h \in gHg^{-1}H$). But if $H \supseteq gHg^{-1}H$, then  $H \supseteq gHg^{-1}$ which goes against being not normal.

Comment: I'm confused. How do I calculate $gHg^{-1}H$?

Comment: @BalancedTryteOperators $gHg^{-1}H = \{gh_1g^{-1}h_2 | h_i \in H\}$

Comment: The problem with this answer is that if you want to check whether some function is a homomorphism then first you need a group on each side. So the real problem is that $G/H$ is not a group.

Comment: There's something I don't get about your proof: you said that it is important that there exists a $g$ such that $gHg^{-1} \neq H$, but I never saw you use this fact in your third paragraph.

Comment: @BalancedTryteOperators an equivalent condition for being normal is $gHg^{-1} \subseteq H \forall g \in G$

Comment: This answer is perfect thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Can you find an instance of a group theorist actually saying this?

Because $G/H$, as a set, is perfectly well-defined, and the map from $G$ to this set is a perfectly nice map of sets. It's not of much interest to group theorists as it stands, however, because they tend to care about homomorphisms, and the set $G/H$ lacks a natural group structure unless $H$ happens to be normal in $G$.

It's also the case that a set theorist might define $\sim_H$ to be the equivalence relation on $G$ defined by $a \stackrel{\tiny H}{\sim} b \Leftrightarrow a^{-1}b \in H$, and then write $G/{\stackrel{\tiny H}{\sim}}$ rather than $G/H$, i.e., "mod" in set theory is usually "modulo an equivalence relation" rather than "modulo a subgroup", but that latter expression is really just shorthand for "modulo the natural equivalence relation associated to this subgroup," and it's a lot easier to write $G/H$.

Answer (score 2):

If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then cosets of $H$ in $G$ form a quotient group in $G$ with the operation defined by $g_1H*g_2H = (g_1g_2)H$.  But this is not well-defined if $H$ is not normal, because we might have $g_3\in g_1 H$ and $g_4\in g_2 H$ but $g_1g_2H\ne g_3g_4H$.

Comment: You are right but I think OP is concerned about the well-definedness of the map $f:G \to G/H$ as opposed to the group operation being well-defined on the quotient set.

Comment: No, this is a correct answer. The standard map $G\to G/H$ **is always** well defined for any subgroup $H$. And you cannot even talk about it "being a homomorphism" if $G/H$ is not a group to begin with.